# Find the angle $\angle \alpha$

Tags: geometry

We have only a triangle with tow angle that I showed. I try many different way for find the $\angle \alpha$ but I didn't find it. Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.

[image]

Updated:
Thanks from THE LONE WOLF and Qwerty. I only test the way of THE LONE WOLF but two way are true for answer.

$\frac{\sin15}{\sin BAD}=\frac{\sin30}{\sin DAC}=\frac{2\sin15\cos15}{\sin DAC}$

$\frac{1}{\sin (\alpha - 15)}=\frac{2\cos15}{\sin (\pi - (\alpha + 30)}=\frac{2\cos15}{\sin (\alpha + 30)}$

$2\cos15(\sin\alpha\cos15 - \sin15\cos\alpha) = \sin(\alpha + 30) $

$(2(\cos15)^2)\sin\alpha - (2\cos15\sin15)\cos\alpha = \sin\alpha\cos30 + \sin30\cos\alpha$

$(\cos30 + 1)\sin\alpha - (\sin30)\cos\alpha = \sin\alpha\cos30 + \sin30\cos\alpha$

$\cos30\sin\alpha + \sin\alpha - \sin30\cos\alpha = \sin\alpha\cos30 + \sin30\cos\alpha$

$\sin\alpha = 2\sin30\cos\alpha = \cos\alpha$

so $\alpha = 45$.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Put BD=CD=1 and use the sine rule in triangles ABD and ADC to create a formula involving the angle BAD only.

Answer (score 1):

The **sine** (of four! ;-)

$$AD=BD{\sin15^\circ\over \sin\theta}=DC{\sin30^\circ\over\sin(135^\circ-\theta)}$$

Where  $\theta =\angle BAD$

Answer (score 1):

In the figure notice that, $BAD=\alpha-15$ and $CAD=(180-\alpha)-30=150-\alpha$  {exterior angle is sum of two interior opposite angles}

Now use Sine rule in Triangle $ABD$ and you will get that $$\frac {\sin15}{AD}=\frac {\sin BAD}{BD}$$ Also on applying Sine rule to triangle $ACD$ you will get that $$ \frac{\sin30}{AD}=\frac{\sin DAC}{DC}$$

Further since you have $BD=CD$ so you will get that $$\frac{\sin30}{\sin DAC}=\frac{\sin15}{\sin BAD}$$

As you know $CAD=150-\alpha$  and $BAD=\alpha-15$ you get $$\frac{\sin30}{\sin(150-\alpha)}=\frac{\sin15}{\sin(\alpha-15)}$$ Now its your turn